# d3 zoom and pan upgrade to version 4

Tags: d3.js

Help would be appreciated updating the code below to work in version 4.  I have changed zoom.behaviour to d3.zoom but I'm not clear about the other changes that are needed.  It looks more complicated than v3!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>-->

   <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
      body, html {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
      }
      svg {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
      }
      p {
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Use the mouse to pan (click and move) / zoom (scrollwheel)</p>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", "100%")
        .attr("height", "100%")
        .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
            svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
        }))
        .append("g")

      svg.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", document.body.clientWidth / 2)
        .attr("cy", document.body.clientHeight / 2)
        .attr("r", 50)
        .style("fill", "#B8DEE6")
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Change this:

```
.call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
    svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate 
    + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
}))
```

To this:

```
.call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
        svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
}))
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/c8bga82b/

Comment: That's great thanks.  Do you know if it is possible to zoom only the x-axis?  Previously I used  zoom = d3.zoom.transform()     .x(xRange)
  //.y(y)

Comment: This works in the fiddle, however in my SVG I am using viewbox and that seems to break it?

Answer (score 9):

I can't reply to your comment to the answer, but here is how to zoom only the x-axis:

```
svg.attr(
    "transform",
    'translate('+d3.event.transform.x+',0) scale('+d3.event.transform.k+',1)'
)}))
```

Updated jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/axge6a04/1/

Comment: you're the best!

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is great !

For those of you who want to **restrict** the pan & zoom in boundaries (like [here](https://gist.github.com/shawnbot/6518285))..

Change this:

```js
// width, height = viewport width, height
.call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
  var tx = Math.min(0, Math.max(d3.event.translate[0], width - width * d3.event.scale));
  var ty = Math.min(0, Math.max(d3.event.translate[1], height - height * d3.event.scale));
  svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + [tx, ty] + ") scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
});
```

To this:

```js
.call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
  d3.event.transform.x = Math.min(0, Math.max(d3.event.transform.x, width - width * d3.event.transform.k));
  d3.event.transform.y = Math.min(0, Math.max(d3.event.transform.y, height - height * d3.event.transform.k));
  svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}));
```

Comment: Great, exactly what I needed! Many examples have `zoom.transform([tx, ty])` to update the zoom object itself, but that function vanished.